EEException: User memory limit exceeded eventhough having only 1 Band and reducing it: reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), pointgeometry)
I run this in GoogleColab
I am loading Modis and Landsat data and reproject Landsat to Modis data:
# pip install eemont
import ee
import eemont

# getting modis properties 
modis_proj = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1") \
                .first().select("NDVI").projection()

# defining region to clip
africa = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/jessicaruijsch-part-1/assets/InputData/AfricaContinent")

# loading Landsat data
new_VI = (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
    .preprocess()
    .filterDate("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31")
    .spectralIndices(["kNDVI", "NIRv"])

kndvi_median = new_VI.select("kNDVI").median()
nirv_median = new_VI.select("NIRv").median()

#reprojection
kndvi_reproj = new_VI.select("kNDVI").median().reproject(
    crs=modis_proj.crs(),
    scale=modis_proj.nominalScale()
)

Then I want to print the minimum pixel value. As this exceeded the limits for the africa region, i defined a point geometry with a buffer to make the computation less heavy:
rainforest_point = ee.Geometry.Point([16.438, -1.559]).buffer(1000)

# Comparing resolutions between Modis:
kndvi_reproj_min = kndvi_reproj.reduceRegion(
    reducer = ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry = rainforest_point,
    scale = 250,
    maxPixels = 1e9,
    bestEffort = True,
    tileScale = 16
)

kndvi_reproj_min["kNDVI_min"].getInfo()

I am wondering, why i get the error "User memory limit exceeded", if I only want to compute one point geometry value within one band?
What am I missing?

I see 2 potential culprit: can you try the same with one of the native band of MODIS ? if it works it means the computation of "kNDVI" and "NIRv" by eemont is more complex than it seems. 2nd option, why do you reproject and change the scale ? it's a very costly operation and very few workflow requires to do it in GEE.
